# Cmake error when cancel External project

Tags: cmake

I am using cmake module ExternalProject to build libcurl and third party library. 
If I cancel building in middle and try to run again

I am getting following error

```
-- curl version=[7.24.0]
CMake Error at CMake/OtherTests.cmake:89 (message):
  Unable to link function recv
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:795 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make[2]: *** [lib/linux/gcc/src/libcurl-stamp/./libcurl-configure] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/libcurl.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Have you tried `make clean` and starting over?

Comment: @olovb after cleaning it will work. It will clean other things also.

Comment: So it is curl's *configuration step* that fails the second time (after the previous configuration was interrupted)? It looks like curl uses CMake itself.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but since it's still around, it would be nice to get a [mre] including the ExternalProject call and what arguments are being passed to it.